# How do you centre an HTML form input box and buttons using CSS?

Tags: html, css

A task I'm attempting; model a certain html page to look like the Google home page. I am struggling to centre  the search bar and the buttons using CSS.

```css
div.search {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <br><input type="text" name="q"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
    <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
  </form>
</div>
```

But the positions of the search box and two buttons don't change.

Comment: block-level elements will span the entire width by default and as such can't be centered horizontally

Comment: You'd have to also give the div a width less than 100% for that to work

Comment: remove `margin` from the div as it is an useless property this way. Use `text-align: center` on the div to center the buttons: `div.search { text-align: center; }`

Comment: thanks @tacoshy, I've been struggling for hours and I didn't realise it was that simple

Answer (score -1):

### You're trying to center inner elements with margin but applying the props to their parent element.

If you want to have **inner elements** centered using `margin`, you need to apply it to them, **NOT** on their **parent**.

Try this:

1. Apply the `margin: 0 auto;` to all your inputs (to center all of them).
2. Set the search bar display to `display: block` (so your search bar ocuppies the entire line)
3. Set the submit buttons display to `display: inline: block;` (so they're are displayed *inline*)
4. Remove both `<br>` around your search input (as they're doing nothing).

### Code:

```css
div.search{
  width: fit-content;
}

input[type="text"]{
  display: block;
}

input[type="submit"]{
  display: inline-block;
}

input{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
    <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you need 16 lines of CSS code that could have done with just 1.

Comment: Yes, but at some point he's going to style all these inputs, or even add more of them.

Comment: Even then it would be easier to use flexbox or text-align and align all the child elements with one property then selecting every single element...